# JQuery validation not working for Base Model classs mvc net core 3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

Below are the Baseclass and Userclass model i have used and i have also added required annotations in both the Base and Derived class . I have used this class in asp.net core razor view page and implemented jquery-validation for this .
I could see validation happening only for derived class but not base class . How can i fix this ?

```
 public class BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string TicketNo { get; set; }
    }

 public class UserRoleModel : BaseModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AddDeleteFlag { get; set; }
    }
```

And my cshtml page

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="TicketNo">Ticket Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Employee" asp-for="TicketNo" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Ticket Number">
                        <span asp-validation-for="TicketNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="UserID">User ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="UserID" asp-for="UserID" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="User ID">
                        <span asp-validation-for="UserID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="RoleName">Role Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="RoleName" asp-for="RoleName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Role Name">
                        <span asp-validation-for="RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="AddRole" asp-for="AddDeleteFlag" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        <input type="submit" value="DeleteRole" asp-for="AddDeleteFlag" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                    </div>
```

i have also added required js reference

```
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

[image]

Now Validation happening only for derived class not base class !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enter the wrong `name` for `TicketNo` property , please modify the markup to below :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="TicketNo">Ticket Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="TicketNo" asp-for="TicketNo" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Ticket Number">
    <span asp-validation-for="TicketNo" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```